# Azure Dev Ops Overview Hub

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

Is it possible to add a hub to the overview group?

[image]

I thought this would do it but I cannot find where this ends up at:

[image]

Alternately, if it is not possible, is it possible to put in a new group all together?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can; your vss-extension.json would look something like this:

```
"contributions": [
    {
      "id": "sample-hub-group",
      "type": "ms.vss-web.hub-group",
      "description": "The  hub group example",
      "targets": [
        "ms.vss-web.project-hub-groups-collection"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "name": "Invoices",
        "icon": {
          "dark": "img/world.png",
          "light": "img/world.png"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "Test.example",
      "type": "ms.vss-web.hub",
      "description": "Adds a 'Example' hub to the Example hub group.",
      "targets": [
          ".sample-hub-group"
      ],
      "properties": {
          "name": "List",
          "uri": "dist/list/list.html"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "default-hub",
      "type": "ms.vss-web.hub",
      "targets": [".sample-hub-group"],
      "properties": {
        "name": "Overview",
        "uri": "dist/hub/hub.html"
      }
    }
```